# Is there a way to substitute recursively and automatically in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am coming from Mathematica, where you can do the following to fully substitute:

```
In[1]:=

x=y
y=z
Simplify[x]

Out[1]=

z
```

Is there a way of doing this automatically in SymPy? I am aware that I can manually substitute the variables 1 by 1 using `subs` or `solve`, or by doing something janky like this:

```
In[1]:

y=z
x=y
x

Out[1]:

z
```

but is there a way of making it *automatically* get the most expanded and substituted expression solving for 1 variable?

Comment: There isn't a way to do this automatically. Your example is too simple for me to be able to suggest an approach for what you are actually trying to do (i.e. your "janky" code seems fine given the example).

Comment: Keep in mind that `y=z` is a Python assignment, not a `sympy` operation.  Reread the `sympy` `gotchas` if that isn't clear.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin What I am actually trying to do is basically the above example but with a lot more variables and equalities, in a context where the required variable might not already be isolated in each equality. I would have to be able to rewrite each equality and _then_ substitute it, but it would have to be able to detect which variable to isolate for each. The "janky" code assumes that I already know which variables will be substituted and they are already isolated in equalities.

Comment: Maybe edit the question to show a more realistic example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proof of concept code [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720) that handles multiple equations.

```
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
eqs = [Eq(x,y),Eq(y,z)]
focus(eqs, z)  # function defined in link
{z: x}
```